# Can someone help me figure out what WMI is doing?

Tags: wmi-query

Here's what I received from running a WMI Trace.  This is approx 60 different events that happen all in 1 second.  So every 60 seconds, these events (and sometimes more) are triggered in WMI.   My WMI service uses whatever available CPU I have to process them, pegging the CPU at %100.   Here's the kicker, I turn off WMI and I have 0 problems with the CPU and my applications work w/out issue...  However, I need WMI on for VM Tools.  Please let me know what you think.  thanks!

```
ProviderInfo for GroupOperationId = 258467; Operation = Provider::GetObject - Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration.Index=2; ProviderName = CIMWin32; ProviderGuid = {d63a5850-8f16-11cf-9f47-00aa00bf345c}; Path = %systemroot%\system32\wbem\cimwin32.dll
ProviderInfo for GroupOperationId = 258467; Operation = Provider::GetObject - Win32_NetworkAdapter.DeviceID="2"; ProviderName = CIMWin32; ProviderGuid = {d63a5850-8f16-11cf-9f47-00aa00bf345c}; Path = %systemroot%\system32\wbem\cimwin32.dll
ProviderInfo for GroupOperationId = 258467; Operation = Provider::GetObject - Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration.Index=1; ProviderName = CIMWin32; ProviderGuid = {d63a5850-8f16-11cf-9f47-00aa00bf345c}; Path = %systemroot%\system32\wbem\cimwin32.dll
ProviderInfo for GroupOperationId = 258467; Operation = Provider::GetObject - Win32_NetworkAdapter.DeviceID="1"; ProviderName = CIMWin32; ProviderGuid = {d63a5850-8f16-11cf-9f47-00aa00bf345c}; Path = %systemroot%\system32\wbem\cimwin32.dll
ProviderInfo for GroupOperationId = 258467; Operation = Provider::GetObject - Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration.Index=0; ProviderName = CIMWin32; ProviderGuid = {d63a5850-8f16-11cf-9f47-00aa00bf345c}; Path = %systemroot%\system32\wbem\cimwin32.dll
ProviderInfo for GroupOperationId = 258467; Operation = Provider::GetObject - Win32_NetworkAdapter.DeviceID="0"; ProviderName = CIMWin32; ProviderGuid = {d63a5850-8f16-11cf-9f47-00aa00bf345c}; Path = %systemroot%\system32\wbem\cimwin32.dll
Stop OperationId = 258468
Stop OperationId = 258498
Stop OperationId = 258499
GroupOperationId = 258467; OperationId = 258499; Operation = Start IWbemServices::GetObject - Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration; ClientMachine = Local; User = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
ProviderInfo for GroupOperationId = 258467; Operation = Provider::ExecQuery - select __RELPATH, __RELPATH, Index from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where Index <> NULL; ProviderName = CIMWin32; ProviderGuid = {d63a5850-8f16-11cf-9f47-00aa00bf345c}; Path = %systemroot%\system32\wbem\cimwin32.dll
GroupOperationId = 258467; OperationId = 258498; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - SELECT __RELPATH, Index FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE Index<>NULL; ClientMachine = Local; User = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
Stop OperationId = 258493
Stop OperationId = 258495
Stop OperationId = 258497
GroupOperationId = 258494; OperationId = 258497; Operation = Start IWbemServices::GetObject - MSFT_SCMEVENTLOGEVENT; ClientMachine = Local; User = .\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
GroupOperationId = 258467; OperationId = 258496; Operation = Start IWbemServices::GetObject - Win32_NetworkAdapter; ClientMachine = Local; User = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
Stop OperationId = 258496
GroupOperationId = 258467; OperationId = 258492; Operation = Start IWbemServices::GetObject - Win32_NetworkAdapterSetting; ClientMachine = Local; User = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
ProviderInfo for GroupOperationId = 258467; Operation = Provider::ExecQuery - select __RELPATH, __RELPATH, Index from Win32_NetworkAdapter where Index <> NULL; ProviderName = CIMWin32; ProviderGuid = {d63a5850-8f16-11cf-9f47-00aa00bf345c}; Path = %systemroot%\system32\wbem\cimwin32.dll
GroupOperationId = 258467; OperationId = 258493; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - SELECT __RELPATH, Index FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE Index <> NULL; ClientMachine = Local; User = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
ProviderInfo for GroupOperationId = 258467; Operation = Provider::CreateInstanceEnum - Win32_NetworkAdapterSetting; ProviderName = CIMWin32; ProviderGuid = {d63a5850-8f16-11cf-9f47-00aa00bf345c}; Path = %systemroot%\system32\wbem\cimwin32.dll
Stop OperationId = 258492
GroupOperationId = 258494; OperationId = 258495; Operation = Start IWbemServices::CreateClassEnum - MSFT_SCMEVENTLOGEVENT; ClientMachine = Local; User = .\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
Stop OperationId = 258491
GroupOperationId = 258459; OperationId = 258491; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - references of {__Win32Provider.Name="SCM Event Provider"}; ClientMachine = Local; User = .\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
Stop OperationId = 258490
GroupOperationId = 258459; OperationId = 258490; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - references of {__Win32Provider.Name="SCM Event Provider"}; ClientMachine = Local; User = .\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
Stop OperationId = 258488
GroupOperationId = 258487; OperationId = 258488; Operation = Start IWbemServices::CreateInstanceEnum - __TimerInstruction; ClientMachine = Local; User = .\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
Stop OperationId = 258482
Stop OperationId = 258489
GroupOperationId = 258467; OperationId = 258489; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - references of {__Win32Provider.Name="CIMWin32"}; ClientMachine = Local; User = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
Stop OperationId = 258486
GroupOperationId = 258486; OperationId = 258486; Operation = IWbemServices::Connect; ClientMachine = ALLE03VMA03; User = NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE; ClientProcessId = 19984; NamespaceName = Root
Stop OperationId = 258484
Stop OperationId = 258485
GroupOperationId = 258467; OperationId = 258481; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - references of {__Win32Provider.Name="CIMWin32"}; ClientMachine = Local; User = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
Stop OperationId = 258480
GroupOperationId = 258483; OperationId = 258485; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - references of {__Win32Provider.Name="WmiPerfClass"}; ClientMachine = Local; User = .\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
GroupOperationId = 258483; OperationId = 258484; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - Select * from __ClassProviderRegistration; ClientMachine = Local; User = .\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
GroupOperationId = 258459; OperationId = 258482; Operation = Start IWbemServices::CreateInstanceEnum - __EventProviderRegistration; ClientMachine = Local; User = .\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
Stop OperationId = 258465
Stop OperationId = 258481
GroupOperationId = 258467; OperationId = 258480; Operation = Start IWbemServices::GetObject - __Win32Provider.Name="CIMWin32"; ClientMachine = Local; User = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
Stop OperationId = 258473
Stop OperationId = 258477
GroupOperationId = 258478; OperationId = 258479; Operation = Start IWbemServices::CreateInstanceEnum - __TimerInstruction; ClientMachine = Local; User = .\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\subscription
Stop OperationId = 258476
GroupOperationId = 258475; OperationId = 258476; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - Select * from __ClassProviderRegistration; ClientMachine = Local; User = .\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\subscription
GroupOperationId = 258467; OperationId = 258477; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - references of {__Win32Provider.Name="WmiPerfClass"}; ClientMachine = Local; User = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
Stop OperationId = 258474
Stop OperationId = 258479
GroupOperationId = 258467; OperationId = 258474; Operation = Start IWbemServices::GetObject - __Win32Provider.Name="WmiPerfClass"; ClientMachine = Local; User = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
GroupOperationId = 258467; OperationId = 258473; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - Select * from __ClassProviderRegistration; ClientMachine = Local; User = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
Stop OperationId = 258472
GroupOperationId = 258459; OperationId = 258472; Operation = Start IWbemServices::CreateClassEnum - __ArbitratorConfiguration; ClientMachine = Local; User = .\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root
Stop OperationId = 258470
Stop OperationId = 258471
GroupOperationId = 258459; OperationId = 258471; Operation = Start IWbemServices::CreateInstanceEnum - __EventProviderRegistration; ClientMachine = Local; User = .\SYSTEM; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\subscription
Stop OperationId = 258466
```

Comment: More information is required.

Comment: " More information is required. –  Okuma.Scott 15 hours ago " I will be happy to provide more info - What else do you need?

Comment: I have narrowed down my issue to C:\Windows\System32\wbem\cimwin32.dll  If I rename this file, I no longer have the high CPU usage.  I would love to know what software is calling for this file though... My server is a VM 2008 R2.  Its used a terminal server (not using terminal server but another software - TSplus) -- I guess I will resort to renaming this for now.  If anyone has more idea's of how I can find the culprit, please advise :)